# Invalid Syntax on perfectly correct while loop?

Tags: python

I am writing a program for fun (hang man) and i get incorrrect syntax on this while loop

```
while wrong MAX_WRONG and so_far != word:
```

My whole program is this

```
import random
HANGMAN=( #this is the Hangman ascii art
"""
_________
   |         |
   |         0
   |        
   |        
   |
   |
 _________
    |         |
    |         0
    |         |
    |        
    |
    |
 _________
    |         |
    |         0
    |        /|\\
    |        
    |
    |
 _________
    |         |
    |         0
    |        /|\\
    |        / \\
    |
    |
""")

MAX_WRONG=len(HANGMAN)-1


WORDS=("OVERUSED","CLAM","BACON","PUCK","TAFFY") #these are the words

word=random.choice(WORDS) #this is teh word that is going to be guessed
so_far="-"*len(word)#where the orrect letteres are viewd
wrong=0
used=[]# the letters incorrectly guessed

while wrong MAX_WRONG and so_far != word:
    print HANGMAN[wrong]
    print "YOu have used:\n",used
    print "\nso far the word is:\n",so_far

guess=raw_input("\n\nEnter your guess:")
guess=guess.upper()

while guess in used:
    print "You have already guessed the letter".guess
    guess=raw_input("enter your guess")
    guess=guess.upper()
    used.append(guess)
if guess in word:
    new=""
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if guess==word[i]:
            new+=guess
        else: 
            new+=so_far[i]
    so_far=new

else:
    print "INCORRECT"
    wrong+=1
if wrong==MAX_WRONG:
    print HANGMAN[wrong]
else:
    print "YAAAAY"

    print "the word was",word
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: "Invalid Syntax on perfectly correct while loop?" doesn't seem that correct to me.

Comment: So, besides just down-votes, can we get some votes to close? :-/

Comment: It's not a good strategy to claim that code is correct when a compiler says it isn't -- most people will believe the compiler.  You'll get fewer downvotes (I didn't pile on - 7 is enough) next time if you say "help me find my error" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wrong MAX_WRONG` does not make sense. You'll need an operator between those two identifiers. You're probably looking for `<`.

Answer (score 4):

`wrong MAX_WORD` is the incorrect syntax. perhaps you want `wrong <= Max_Wrong`

Answer (score 1):

```
while wrong < MAX_WRONG and so_far != word:
```

Is this what you mean?(Note `<` comparator)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant `wrong < MAX_WRONG`...